# Where are the batteries in the first area?

Tags: operation-smash

When I first found the door which requires batteries, I avoided the sparking things on the ground, because obviously sparks=danger. I continued exploring and found various batteries, but could only carry the one. I finally discovered that I was supposed to put the batteries on the sparking bits, but now I can't find one of the batteries. Where are the batteries located in the first area of Operation Smash?